Is there a way to add close and add buttons to tabs in tkinter.ttk.Notebook?
enter image description here
I want to achieve the effect displayed in the picture. Click the plus sign to add a tag, click close to close the tag.
I can do it with two separate features, but I can't do it with two features combined.
How do I achieve this by ttk.Notebook?

For the close button, see this question: is-there-a-way-to-add-close-buttons-to-tabs-in-tkinter-ttk-notebook.

According to this method, my plus button also has a close icon, which is not what I want

As suggested in the comments by @acw1668, for close buttons you can simply use the code from this answer.
As for the "Add" button, I think there are several ways to create it. I will show you a method that will create an additional "Add" tab. The basic idea is that you simply set this "Add" tab state to "disabled" and add additional logic to the close button code to perform special actions if the tab is "disabled".
Add the "Add" tab in the __init__ method:
...
ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
self.add(tk.Frame(self), state='disabled')  # "+" tab
...

Modify the on_close_press method to add additional logic in case the "Add" button is pressed:
...
index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
if self.tab(index, 'state') == 'disabled':  # "+" tab is pressed
    self.add_new_tab(index)
    return "break"
...

Where add_new_tab is your method that creates a new tab.
Now add the "+" image to the self.images:
...
tk.PhotoImage("img_add", data='''
    iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
    AARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAB+SURBVChTY2ZA
    AyJSxtVcPFJq3748Pw8VAgMmKI0EGHkZGZi4oBw4wKIQOyBaISPITSDroHyG//8Z
    7IHkF0ZGxrNQIQZGxv/vmRj+M7xg/M/4FIZBioByH1HE/jO9hGhBAiJSJh2ikqa5
    UC4cUN8zGApBDmdgZPgM5UIBAwMAe9MjkX8aHzEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=''')
...

And finally just add an extra "disabled" case to element_create:
...
("disabled", "img_add"),
...

Full code (with example for method add_new_tab):
class CustomNotebook(ttk.Notebook):
    """A ttk Notebook with close buttons on each tab"""

    __initialized = False

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.__initialized:
            self.__initialize_custom_style()
            self.__inititialized = True

        kwargs["style"] = "CustomNotebook"
        ttk.Notebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.add(tk.Frame(self), state='disabled')  # "+" tab

        self._active = None

        self.bind("<ButtonPress-1>", self.on_close_press, True)
        self.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", self.on_close_release)

    def on_close_press(self, event):
        """Called when the button is pressed over the close button"""

        element = self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if "close" in element:
            index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))
            if self.tab(index, 'state') == 'disabled':  # "+" tab is pressed
                self.add_new_tab(index)
                return "break"
            self.state(['pressed'])
            self._active = index
            return "break"

    def on_close_release(self, event):
        """Called when the button is released"""
        if not self.instate(['pressed']):
            return

        element =  self.identify(event.x, event.y)
        if "close" not in element:
            # user moved the mouse off of the close button
            return

        index = self.index("@%d,%d" % (event.x, event.y))

        if self._active == index:
            self.forget(index)
            self.event_generate("<<NotebookTabClosed>>")

        self.state(["!pressed"])
        self._active = None

    def add_new_tab(self, add_index):
        """Adds a new tab on button "+" pressed"""
        pass
        # Your code for the new tab there. Example:
        self.insert(add_index, tk.Label(text='Just a test tab'), text='NewTab')
        self.select(add_index)

    def __initialize_custom_style(self):
        style = ttk.Style()
        self.images = (
            tk.PhotoImage("img_close", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIBAAAAADs7O4+Pj9nZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closeactive", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAP/SAP/bNNnZ2cbGxsbGxsbGxsbGxiH5BAEKAAQALAAA
                AAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU5kEJADs=
                '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_closepressed", data='''
                R0lGODlhCAAIAMIEAAAAAOUqKv9mZtnZ2Ts7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7OyH+EUNyZWF0ZWQg
                d2l0aCBHSU1QACH5BAEKAAQALAAAAAAIAAgAAAMVGDBEA0qNJyGw7AmxmuaZhWEU
                5kEJADs=
            '''),
            tk.PhotoImage("img_add", data='''
                iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAoAAAAKCAYAAACNMs+9AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAA
                AARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAB+SURBVChTY2ZA
                AyJSxtVcPFJq3748Pw8VAgMmKI0EGHkZGZi4oBw4wKIQOyBaISPITSDroHyG//8Z
                7IHkF0ZGxrNQIQZGxv/vmRj+M7xg/M/4FIZBioByH1HE/jO9hGhBAiJSJh2ikqa5
                UC4cUN8zGApBDmdgZPgM5UIBAwMAe9MjkX8aHzEAAAAASUVORK5CYII=''')  # "+" image
        )

        style.element_create("close", "image", "img_close",
                            ("active", "pressed", "!disabled", "img_closepressed"),
                            ("active", "!disabled", "img_closeactive"),
                            ("disabled", "img_add"), border=8, sticky='')
        style.layout("CustomNotebook", [("CustomNotebook.client", {"sticky": "nswe"})])
        style.layout("CustomNotebook.Tab", [
            ("CustomNotebook.tab", {
                "sticky": "nswe",
                "children": [
                    ("CustomNotebook.padding", {
                        "side": "top",
                        "sticky": "nswe",
                        "children": [
                            ("CustomNotebook.focus", {
                                "side": "top",
                                "sticky": "nswe",
                                "children": [
                                    ("CustomNotebook.label", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                    ("CustomNotebook.close", {"side": "left", "sticky": ''}),
                                ]
                        })
                    ]
                })
            ]
        })
    ])

One last thing: remember that the "Add" button is a tab, so if you add other tabs using the Notebook.add() command, the new tabs will be added after the "Add" tab. So you can use the notebook. insert() command instead.
Note. This code can still be improved. For example, you can add an additional image (and logic) to make the "Add" tab more dynamic, just like it is done with the "close" buttons.

Works great! Thanks!

To achieve the described effect using ttk.Notebook, you need to create a custom tab that includes both a tag and a close button. Here's a concise way to do this:
Create a Frame for the tab: This frame will include both the tag (label) and the close button.
Add the Frame to the Notebook: Insert the frame into the ttk.Notebook as a tab.
Bind the Close Button: Attach a command to the close button to remove the tab.

code example : import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
def add_tab():
frame = ttk.Frame(notebook)
label = ttk.Label(frame, text="New Tag")
label.pack(side="left")
close_btn = ttk.Button(frame, text="x", command=lambda: notebook.forget(frame))
close_btn.pack(side="right")

notebook.add(frame, text="")

Main Application
root = tk.Tk()
notebook = ttk.Notebook(root)
notebook.pack(expand=True, fill='both')
add_button = ttk.Button(root, text="+", command=add_tab)
add_button.pack()
root.mainloop()

Please post the code inside the answer so that it can keep it's newlines and indentation. It's also much easier to modify later or add syntax highlighting.

Thank you, but the effect I want is the effect in my picture, clearly your code is far from what I need

What you want to do is difficult to achieve with tkinter because you would need two kinds of tabs: normal tabs with a close button and an extra tab with an "add" icon.
A not-too-complex way of achieving a result reasonably similar top what you would like is to take the CustomNotebook class from Is there a way to add close buttons to tabs in tkinter.ttk.Notebook? to get the close button on the tabs and add an extra "add" button in the top left corner of the notebook to create new tabs:
class AddBtnNotebook(CustomNotebook):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        CustomNotebook.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self._img = tk.PhotoImage(data=b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x10\x08\x06\x00\x00\x00\x1f\xf3\xffa\x00\x00\x00\xb3IDATx\x9c\xb5\xd31j\x82A\x14\x04\xe0\xef\x89v\xb1H)hk*/\x912x\x81\x94\x9e\xc0\xce\xcb\xd8\xeb\xa9\xb41`\x93\x80`J\xc9\xa6QX\x7fw\xe1\x8f\x92\x81)fwf\xd8]\xdeJ))\x11\x0b|\xe1\x13\xf3\xaa\xaf\x12\x9e e\xfc\xc1\xb8\xe4\xed(c\xd4\xd0\x81a\xc9X+h\x8d\x87\x0b\xba\x10\x11]\xf4\xb3\xf5\xa7\x82\xb7\x1f\x11\xcf\x99>\xa6\x94N0\xc5\xc1\xf5\xa3\xb5\xe1\xe1\x9c\xb5\xbd#|\xe16p\xac\x1c\xb9\r\xbe;X\xdd\x19\x86U\xa0\x87w\x0c\xb2\x8d\x17\xcc\x1a\xe6%6\x99\xdec]\x9b\xc47\xb7\xf7}\xfd\xcb$\xb6\xc6\xbf\x15\xec\x1a:\xe1\xa3\xe8|\xf4;\xff\x02/@\xbfn\x03\x8cH\xb7\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82')
        self.add_button = ttk.Button(self, image=self._img, command=self.add_tab, padding=0)
        self.add_button.place(relx=1, rely=0, anchor="ne")
    
    def add_tab(self):
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        notebook.add(frame, text="New Tab")

The above code can also be directly integrated in the original code of the CustomNotebook but I did not want to repeat it here since it is already available with explanations in Is there a way to add close buttons to tabs in tkinter.ttk.Notebook?.
Disclaimer: this solution does not handle very well resizing (the add button overlaps with the tabs) and it is not always next to the last tab as in the picture in the question.
